# How to pass selected value of kendo UI DropDownList to javascript onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, kendo-ui

Razor view

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
     <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().ToolBar()
            .Name("ToolBar_LeftStoragePane")
            .Items(items =>
            {
               items.Add().Overflow(ShowInOverflowPopup.Auto).Type(CommandType.ButtonGroup).Buttons(buttons =>
               {
                  buttons.Add().Text("Rotate").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "rotate-storage-button storage-panel-button", @onclick = "javascript:SetStoragePanelMode(this)" });
                  buttons.Add().Text("Move").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "pan-storage-button storage-panel-button", @onclick = "javascript:SetStoragePanelMode(this)" });
                  buttons.Add().Text("Zoom").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "zoom-storage-button storage-panel-button", @onclick = "javascript:SetStoragePanelMode(this)" });
                  buttons.Add().Text("Reset").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "reset-storage-button storage-panel-button", @onclick = "javascript:SetStoragePanelMode(this)" });
               });

               items.Add().Template("<input id='Dropdown' style='width: 100px;' />").Id("LeftView").Overflow(ShowInOverflowPopup.Never).HtmlAttributes(new { @onclick = "javascript:SwitchStorageView(this)" });

            })
        )

     </div>
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
     dataTextField: "text",
     dataSource: [
         { text: "Front" },
         { text: "Back" },
         { text: "Top" },
         { text: "Bottom" },
         { text: "Left" },
         { text: "Right" },
     ]

  });
 }); <script>
```

Javascript

```
 $(LeftPanel).on('mouseover', function () {
     debugger;
     $("#LeftView").on("click", function () {    
        SwitchStorageView(theView);
     });
  });
```

DropDownList is in kendo ToolBar and in this dropdownlist I have all sides name as written in script tag. whatever side I will select , I want to send that text to javascript code. But I am getting undefined value for theView parameter.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: Why not just use a change event on the dropdown? See [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change).

Comment: Yes, It worked out ! Thank you :)